# How to show only first 3 products in whislist

Tags: magento2, cart, wishlist

I am showing wishlist in my cart page. But I want to show only first 3 wishlist product in my cart page in Magento 2

Comment: Fetch the collection and use LIMIT function

Comment: i have ftech the collection wishlist are showing

Comment: Then just put Limit function in collection till 3 and it will work!